# Replace a color inside a png

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, svg

I have a site where I want to change a color of an image.
I have a simple png like this:

```
<img src="arrow.png" alt="" id="arrow" />
```

[image]

I want to change the color inside in another and after to another if I want.

I have tried in this mode but doesn't work with SVG, doesn't change the color of my image

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <image style=fill:#000000"  xlink:href="arrow.png" />  
</svg>
```

I need a solution in PHP or javascript or jQuery, I have seen GD library in PHP but I want to apply the change of the color to an existing element with an id like my image.

How to solve this?

Comment: Does this have to be done on the fly?  Can you just change the color of the arrow in Photoshop/GIMP, and then use javascript and jquery to swap the photos out?

Comment: why don't you just use a simple SVG image? Changing colors is easy peasy with that.

Comment: Do you actually need to change the colour of the arrow, or could you get away with an alpha transparent arrow (with a solid foreground -- white in your example), which reveals a different coloured background?

Comment: I can have all possibility color and I have about 100 image that can be edit.. 100*16.000.000. isn't possbile @webdevsoup

Comment: doesn't work because apply a filter to all image and I want to apply color not in the background @roasted

Comment: can you make an example? @Christoph

Comment: Use SVG. You'll have a fully scriptable DOM tree of your image available.

Comment: How about using an icon font (loads of common ones [here](http://fontello.com/))

Comment: ok an example with my case? I never used SVG @BartFriederichs

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri SVG is an XML based image format. You can use Inkscape to create them and/or easily integrate them in HTML. Loads of info to be found online about it.

Comment: ok but I haven't understand how to apply to an image I have seen how to drag a circle and fill it, but I have complex image @BartFriederichs

Comment: are all of those images going to be simple monochrome icons? If so, then simply make the "color" part transparent, and use some css/positioning/background image to "fill" the transparent area with the desired color.

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri use a tool like Inkscape to create the SVG, edit the XML to add `id` attributes, and you can use `document.getElementById()` to get elements and manipulate them. You can even use jQuery or dojo.

Comment: is a dynamic assignment, I have a colorpicker when I select the image that I want I can change the color of it, and I have another div under my image where it can be of different color, for this I need that the background is transparent and not inside.. @MarcB

Comment: http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/data-visualisation/mouseover-effects-svgs

Comment: check out some CSS "Filters" - You may be able to use "hue-rotate"...

Comment: edit question with the example with SVG doesn't work @BartFriederichs

Comment: edit question with the example with SVG doesn't work @Christoph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested you might as well just use an SVG

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <path id="arrow" fill="#000000" d="m1,65 h172 l-64,-64 h50 l82,82 -82,82 h-50 l64,-64 h-172z"/>
</svg>
```

You can select the element with the id and change the fill (or use style="fill:#000000").

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question wasn't tagged with CSS3, but for those who find it helpful, or who are simply unaware that it's possible to use `-mask-box-image` in conjunction with `background` to "mask" images with solid colors, other images, or even [as this example shows] with `gradients`. Given the programatic accessibility, this can be changed on the fly with minimal scripting, if desired.

#### Markup

```
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
.arrow {
     width: 250px;
     height: 250px;
     -webkit-mask-box-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jkhG.png');
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 38% 0%, 60% 70%, from(#dde9f0), to(#3fc5f8), color-stop(.6,#79b2ec),color-stop(.7,#2e91e5));
}
```

#### Result

[image: Result]

#### Plunk

http://plnkr.co/edit/717iDTzblDQfFSkaT2N6?p=preview

Obviously, it's important to be aware of the vendor-prefix, and supported environments.

Comment: would be a nice solution if webkit wasn't the only one supporting this... So practically unusable for at least the next 2 years.

Comment: not works in firefox and I don't think that in IE works... but in Chrome works fine... but I need a solution for all browser is possible?

Comment: @Christoph, I don't disagree. Although, "practically unusable" is subjective. 
OP, Here's a good read on a cross-browser solution that uses the method above and an svg-fallback elsewhere: [http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking](http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking)

Comment: If you need an svg fallback for 50% of the browsers, just *use* svg in the first place.

Comment: Fair point, @Christoph. Seems like you have more than enough reputation to post an answer; why not give this one a go?

Answer (score 1):

You can just cut the black parts in photoshop and make them transparent, then you can apply a background to the image like this:

```
<img style="background: red;" src="arrow.png">
```

It works on all browsers.

Comment: I can't because I have another image under, I need the background transparent

Comment: the image is over another image and I don't want that the background cover the image, I don't want to see the background

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri can you use svg instead of png?

Comment: I can but how after can I change the color? I have to load the image from a source isn't important the extension, the important is that the background is transparent and the "content" color changable

Comment: make a path, and fill it with your desired color using css.
 Then you can change the color in the css dynamically using php or something like that.

Comment: You'll be working with text instead of binary which makes it easier.

Comment: can you make an example in jsfiddle, because I don't understand how to use path to load animage from url

Comment: You don't load an image, you draw it. It needs some work to get this done (draw the image) but here's some help http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp

Comment: you just create a `<path>` and then change `fill="#000"` to whatever you want.

Comment: but I haven't understand how to put an image into <path> isn't clear, make an example please

Comment: perfect but how to find this? d="M100 0 L200 100 L100 200 Z" I haven't understand this of path... can you explain?

Comment: you just need to draw the exact arrow in your image with path. here you can find what d means: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp

Comment: because I have an image, I don't have to create runtime it

Comment: You can also use GUI tools like Adobe Illustrator to make SVG

Comment: And with Illustrator if i load a png can return me this string?

Comment: no, you can use the png as a guide and use the pen tool to draw the exact shape, then delete the png and it will give you an svg file ready to use.

Comment: If I create an svg I can have the string that you have put into the path?

Comment: or try searching for "Online png to svg converter". though i suggest you learn how to make svg.

Comment: with the online converter I retrieve this:<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="250.000000pt" height="250.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 250.000000 250.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<metadata>
Created by potrace 1.11, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2013
</metadata>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,250.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
</g>
</svg> 

but doesn't appear.. uhm..

Comment: here's the best way to do it (without the knowledge of svg)
go to this link: http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.5.1/editor/svg-editor.html then press 8 (image tool) and put the url of your image. after that use the path tool (press 6) and draw the exact shape of the arrow. go back to the select tool (press 1) and choose the path object you just drew and you'll find two fields on the top of the page, X and Y, change both to 0. Then select your image (not the path) and delete it. On the top left you'll find a "view source" button click it and you'll get svg code.

Comment: Also use zoom (bottom left) to draw the exact shape of the arrow when needed. And remove the border using the tool in the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your help, +1 for the patient and the explaination

Answer (score 0):

You can't make this on fly. For example you can generate this image by PHP script and store it for each color. You can make this in local computer and upload 100 images to server. Or you can generate it on server and use "permanent" cache. For example use link arrow.php?color=000000

Script will check in folder file with name 000000.png and if file exists then pass it to browser. Else script will generate new image with this color, save it to file 000000.png and pass it to browser.